# Listview with Sections:How to identify which item of perticular section is clicked

Tags: android

I am using setOnItemClickListener for the list with sections. I have two sections in this list I want that if any item/row of 1st section is clicked it sholud start new activity and If any item of 2nd section is click it should do nothing. How can i identify that the item belong to which section???? Please help
code snippet

```
 SectionedAdapter adapter = new SectionedAdapter() {
             protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 TextView result = (TextView) convertView;


                 if (convertView == null) {
                     result = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
                 }
                 if(caption != null){ 
                        result.setText(caption); 
                        }else{ 
                            result.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        } 


                 return (result);
             }
         };

                    ListView lister;
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
                    {
                      super.onCreate(icicle);
                      setContentView(R.layout.main);
                          lister=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lister);
                      first();
                      second();
                     }
                    first()
                    {
                    arr=...// some array of elements to be in first list

                    firstadapter fa=new firstadapter(this,R.layout.list,arr);
                    adapter.addSection("Old",fa );
                    lister.setAdapter(adapter);

                   }
                  second()
                  {
                   arr=...// some array of elements to be in second list

                  secondadapter sa=new secondadapter(this,R.layout.list,arr);
                  adapter.addSection("Old",sa );
                  lister.setAdapter(adapter);

                  }
                 class firstAdapter extends BaseAdapter
                 {
                ...
                 }
                 class secondAdapter extends BaseAdapter
                 {
                ...
                 }

              abstract class SectionAdapter extends BaseAdapter
              {
         ...
               }
```

Comment: how you create listview with sections...

Comment: I have used sectioned adapter class and to that i have passed the section name and the aaray

Comment: Please elaborate your Query. Is there any data in both sections or it is a single data ??

Comment: @RajaReddy: here you go --  http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: I have use similar code as jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/…  and i want the setOnItemClickListener method that wil identify which sections element/item is clicked

Answer (score 1):

I would set a tag on your arg1

`onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2.....`

setTag(Object) if you want to put some extra information to distinguish between your Views within a ListView's items.

hope this helps.

Comment: How should i use setTag and where in the method itself setOnItemClickListener ?? sorry but not cleared how to use settag

Comment: When you build your adapter for a ListView you have either RelativeLayout with bunch of other views inside or else. Anyways it's a view when you're creating your Adapter at the getView(...) point you assign your setTag(with your distinguished parameter) for a certain view and when you're doing your ItemClick you get that TAG off this arg1.getTag() and it returns Object and you're free to do with it whatever you want.

Comment: this is how i'm also using to make it work. Use getTag() and setTag()

Comment: I tried to toast the value of arg1.getTag() in onItem click method but my application is forcefully closed after clicking any item and  null pointer exception is thrown.If suppose i have two section in one list say "NEW" and "OLD" so how should i use that settag

Comment: when you are setting NEW list's adapter, set tag in its override getView() method, and when setting OLD list's adapter, do the same. Once both adapters are set, add them into sharky's separatedAdapter and bind to the list. At last, set onItemClickListener for listview and fetch getTag out from view parameter... I hope it explains, else post fragments of your code and i see if i can help you to modify

Comment: see the code i've attached for you. Mark it answer if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You will know ListView's itemclickListener only tells you what item in list was clicked.this item is inflated during getView that returns a view.If i am understanding your question correctly then here you can use getChild to know the specific view that was clicked .Something like...

```
ListView.setItemCLickListener(new ItemCLickListener(){
    onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2.....){
    View childYouWant=(View)     arg1.getChild();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView()` you can get the type of the view you are using to create a section. You can get the type of View that you are using by `getItemViewType()`. [`Here`](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) is a complete example for the same which explains that how it works

Answer (score 0):

you are not clear with your question. Are you creating two list or same list you have given two sections. Any way you can do what ever want based on the position value. you can get the position in View getView overrride function inside ArrayAdapter class.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrowlayout, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
        rowView.setTag(position, Long.valueOf(user_ids[position]));

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    if (user_ids[position] == 1) {
        // do something
    } else if (user_ids[position] == 2) 
        // do something         
    }
```

Comment: I am clear with my question only forget to mention that i am using one list with two sections in it. and about the position i am getting positions 0,1,2... till count of items in list. but that is not helpful for me to identify section

Comment: you know which items will go in first section and you know which items will go to the second section. What's the problem with assigning the tag for an item till it reaches a certain index????

Comment: assigning the tag-- i don't know how to assign tag.. Please ellaborate

Comment: so you are done, now you just need to apply your logic to differentiate the section based on the position. E.g you can set some flag value and all.

Comment: @Arfin.Sorry but I think still the scenario is not cleared to you.

Comment: what exactly you are asking is nothing but a logic which can be implement in many ways it is not dependend on any listner or any functions, just try it you will get it.

Comment: @Arfin I am not asking for logic. I am new to android and i have not used this listview with sections before so don't know how to handle that why just asking that if there is any inbuilt method that i have missed out which returns the section name. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sharky's code then do the following modifications to make it work. I've changed his activity's code to make it work simple in my way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import se.phoniro.phone.adapters.SeparatedListAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class temp extends Activity{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Holder> dataNew = new ArrayList<Holder>();
    ArrayList<Holder> dataOld = new ArrayList<Holder>();

    MyCustomAdapter adapterNew, adapterOld;


    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
        super.onCreate(icicle);  

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        dataNew.add(new Holder(DataType.New, "first"));
        dataNew.add(new Holder(DataType.New, "second"));
        dataNew.add(new Holder(DataType.New, "third"));
        adapterNew = new MyCustomAdapter(dataNew);

        dataOld.add(new Holder(DataType.Old, "first"));
        dataOld.add(new Holder(DataType.Old, "second"));
        dataOld.add(new Holder(DataType.Old, "third"));
        adapterOld = new MyCustomAdapter(dataOld);

        // create our list and custom adapter  
        SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);  
        adapter.addSection("New Data", adapterNew);  
        adapter.addSection("Old Data", adapterOld);

        ListView list = new ListView(this);  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.setContentView(list);  


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {

                //here i'm fetching the tag is set at the time in getView
                Holder kv = (Holder)v.getTag();
                //showing selection
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), kv.item + " is of type: " + kv.type.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    } 



    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Holder>{
        ArrayList<Holder> data = null;
        public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Holder> objects) {
            super(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
            data = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            Holder kv = data.get(position);
            tv.setText(kv.item);

            //setting tag to the view
            tv.setTag(kv);

            return tv;
        }
    }


    //custom stuff
    public enum DataType{Old,New}

    class Holder{
        public DataType type;
        public String item = "";

        public Holder(DataType t, String str){
            type = t;
            item = str;
        }

    }

}
```

hope it serves what you are expecting :)

Comment: I am using BaseAdapter and it gives this error "type BaseAdapter is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <ListViewExample.Holder>"

Comment: any adapter extends BaseAdapter, but its upto us which extended class we use for our comfort. Here i'm using ArrayAdapter as it does what i need. Why do you need (or how are you using) BaseAdapter? If your implementation is not complicated enough then i would suggest using ArrayAdapter. P.S. you dont need to change anything in sharky's adapter implementation, just throw any of your new adapter to it and it will do the magic